# How do I implement tmdb into a Laravel 6 project?

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I'm developing a movie review site for college project and I was wondering how would I implement tmdb in Laravel 6, all the tutorials I've seen don't really explain this very well. I'm fairly new to laravel too,  I have a 'Movies' page in which I can display all movies and users can view information on a certain movie, is it possible to pull all the data from the tmdb and display it on my Page? instead of having to insert all the data manually into my database??

Comment: Show what you've tried so far

Comment: @RMPR See I don't really understand api's or how to implement them , I haven't tried to do so because all the tutorials I've seen are all using laravel 5 and don't explain it very well, I just want to be able to display info on movies without having to do it manually in my db

Comment: you have to try something ... there are composer packages you can use for interacting with TMDB to make life way way easier